# How to deploy phonegap to different platform?

Tags: cordova

i understand we need to create for each platform but using the same sources, but if the original one i build using android, is it okay to import the project where it include the android jar library, android xml, and others? and also, can we test ex android phonegap app with ipad? or maybe iphone? my mentor ask me to develop android for phonegap but keep asking to test using ipad. can or not?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that of Phonegap app is just a native application that launches a webview, a navigator window. So, it is written in Objective-c for iOS, Java for Android and so on.. So you have to create a project for each OS you want to develop on.

Also, you can't try an android app on an iPad as iOS don't understand Java application..

Comment: this means i only can test my android phonegap using android smartphone right? i just need to install the .apk right? but i knew is phonegap using html5, javascript and css right?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not use android app in ios you need to use ios platform for test in ipad or iphone you have to Mac Os and Developer tools like Xcode. For Create Phonegap Project in iOS follow command line Interface for this refer This link [Create Phonegap project in Xcode](http://grdevore.screenstepslive.com/s/ispring-phonegap/m/8836/l/91464-lesson-4-creating-the-xcode-project-using-phonegap). Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) app with the [Android Development Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), and then use [Phonegap Build](http://build.phonegap.com/) to package it for iOS.

If you are simply used to using Eclipse or Jetbrains it might be easier to take this route. Also if your developer machine is not a Mac it may be impossible for you to develop using Xcode.

There are ways to test Phonegap apps without deploying to an Android device, like the android emulator or [phonegap-debug](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap).

To build for iOS you will need to have the iOS dev environment, aka Xcode, set up somewhere, possibly on your iPad, to generate license keys for your app, but other than that, depending on what your app does, you should be set.

It is NOT necessary to import the android jar library, android xml, and others. Just what is under the assets/www/ directory, all the html, css, and javascript. You will also need a [config.xml file](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) to tell phonegap build how to configure your project for Android and/or iOS.